# Mysterious line of Javascript code

Tags: javascript, web

I am investigating a bug in some software that has uses an in-house developed Javascript library. The error that I am dealing with appears on the line below:

```
GetVal1("dispLetter")(GetVal1("dispLetter").selectedIndex).value + '~' + (bFinal == true ? '1' : '0');
```

I initially wasn't sure if this line was even valid, however, according to source control this line was around since this file was created while the error is relatively recent. When I debugged I discovered that this line throws an error that says `GetVal1(...) is not a function`. I double checked to confirm that the Javascript file with the function definition is included, the header looks like this:

```
function GetVal1(strHTMLId)
```

So, I guess my question is, is this line valid Javascript code? Is there anything you can tell that could be throwing the error? Thank you.

Comment: In order to be used that way, `GetVal1` has to *return* a function definition.  Is it doing that?

Comment: @ExplosionPills Just checked, its returning an `HTMLSelectElement`. Is that an issue?

Comment: It looks to me like someone has copy-pasted the snippet `GetVal1("dispLetter")` once too often. What is the line supposed to do?

Comment: Btw, you might change `(bFinal == true ? '1' : '0')` to `(+bFinal)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
GetVal1("dispLetter")(GetVal1("dispLetter").selectedIndex).value + ...
```

does the following:

- calls `GetVal1` with the argument `"dispLetter"`.
- calls `GetVal1` with the argument `"dispLetter"`, again.
- retrieves the property `selectedIndex` of the return value of the second invocation of `GetVal1`
- Calls the return value of the first invocation of `GetVal1`, with one argument, the value of `selectedIndex`. This fails your case, and complains the value is not callable.
- The return value's `value` property is dereferenced. String concatenation follows.

In other words, this code seems to assume that the first invocation of `GetVal1("dispLetter")` returns a function (which is unusual), and the second invocation returns an object with the property `selectedIndex` (which is unusual, given the first invocation returns a function).

Some ideas:

- If there used to be a `new` keyword before the line. Then the first invocation would be a constructor call. It is unexpected that a constructor call would return a function while a non-constructor call would not, though.
- If there used to be a trailing period on the previous line (or is now), `GetVal1` would refer (or refers now) to a property of some object. I smell a violation of naming conventions, though, if `GetVal1` is meant to be an object property.
- The global `GetVal1` is (or recently ceased to be) shadowed by a function of the same name. Once again, I smell a violation of naming conventions.
- Most likely, `GetVal1` itself has changed. Verify `GetVal1` can return a function when given this string as the first argument.
- Perhaps the *state* bound to the `GetVal1` function has changed (say, one more extra call somewhere before the code. This most likely a design error, though, if this function returns a different type of object on each invocation with the same arguments. But then again, there likely *is* a design error or naming violation somewhere in the code.
- Another plausible explanation is that this line was there from the beginning, but it was never reached before. In this case, it could have been wrong the whole time.

Comment: I'd opt for the last reason :-)